# Strong params rails 4 permitting params

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

Here is what my params look like,

```
{
:project_id => "1",
:ticket => {:name => "Ticket1"}
}
```

How do I add the **project_id** to the permitted params?

**Controller**

> params.require(:ticket).permit(:name)

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did
I added another function for project params

```
   def ticket_group_params
      params.require(:ticket_group).permit(:name)      
   end

   def project_params
      params.permit(:project_id)
   end
```

Then I just merge the results only for the create action eg.

```
  # POST /ticket_group
  # POST /ticket_group.json
  def create
    @ticket_group = TicketGroup.new(ticket_group_params.merge(project_params))
    respond_to do |format|
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def ticket_params
 name_params = params.require(:ticket).permit(:name)
 name_params.merge(params.permit(:project_id))
end
# => {name: 'val', project_id: 'val'}
```

or

```
def ticket_params
  params.require(:ticket).permit(:name).tap do |_params|
    _params[:project_id] = params.permit(:project_id)
  end
end
# => {name: 'val', project_id: 'val'}
```

or, it may be

```
def ticket_params
  params.permit(:project_id, ticket: [:name])
end
# => {project_id: 'val', ticket: {name: 'val'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to add this as a hidden attribute on your form, like so:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ticket[project_id]" value="<%= @ticket.project_id %>" />
```

Then in the controller you can do this:

```
params.require(:ticket).permit(:name,:project_id)
```

Here is a helpful link:
https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters